# Why does a numpy int16 take 24 bytes

Tags: python-2.7, memory, integer, size

I am trying to figure out the system memory some python variables take

In the following code:

```
    >>> a = numpy.int16(1)
    >>> a.nbytes
    2
    >>> sys.getsizeof(a)
    24
```

Why does a numpy int16 take 24 bytes of space according to sys.getsizeof() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

> getsizeof() calls the object’s __sizeof__ method and adds an **additional garbage collector overhead** if the object is managed by the garbage collector.

So:

**sys.sizeof** is the size of **the whole object**, warts and all;

**nbytes** returns the memory used just by the array's actual **data only**, no frills.

Comment: Understand. So when debugging for memory issues, the sys.sizeof returned value is actually the one to consider? (I know this is outside the scope of the original question and I will accept your answer. But would appreciate your comment on this)

Comment: Well, I'd say either is, depending on what you're trying to debug (issues on the C side of Numpy would be better diagnosed without adding interpreter overhead to the equation), but sizeof will probably be more common.